# Number of awarded points is not being displayed correctly.

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar

Lately I've noticed a strange bug-like behaviour of the site:

[image]

As you can see, I was awarded +5 points for  a question. However the little box on the top of the screen says that I've got +3.

I know it's not a particularly big flaw, but this has happened more often to me.  Am I the only one who's having/has noticed this "problem". Or is there perhaps an explanation for this.

Comment: One thing that can happen is this: you are not notified when you loose points for some reason. Thus, if you have -2, say due to a down-vote, and later +5, then the change since the last increase will be shown, so +3. However, normally you should then see in the list this negative event too. I am thus not sure what exactly happens in your specific case.

Comment: I think it is changes that are a result of posts being deleted that do not show up in that list.  This also includes points gained from downvoted answers being deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You lost two points for an approved edit suggestion when [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856315/the-greatest-common-divisor-of-three-homogeneous-polynomial-in-three-variables) was deleted (by [Community♦](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)) earlier today, so your reputation *change* of $(+5) + (-2) = +3$ was indicated in the top bar.

If you check the "show removed posts" box at the bottom of the [reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) of your profile, you should see a notification of such events there.

Comment: Wow, I never noticed that checkbox. That's awesome.

Comment: One wonders why there is no notification of the change when it is *negative*. Only when the total becomes positive one is notified. This leads to strange behaviour, and consequently meta posts like this one.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I asked about that before. But probably in a comment. The reply was that the box is "positive" so it should only show positive changes.

Comment: @Lord_Farin See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219652/why-do-reputation-drops-not-highlight-the-achievements-icon) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements). Unfortunately, displaying negative reputation changes in the top bar has a firm [meta-tag:status-declined] :(