# Weird stuff with reputation

Tags: support, reputation

Something strange has just happened to my reputation. It suddenly fell from 3067 to 3032, but no reputation changes were indicated in my reputation tab. Does anybody know, what has happened? Is this some sort of bug, or did I miss something?

Comment: I've had this happen before on several occasions, i.e., my reputation decreasing but no reputation changes indicated in my reputation tab.  In every case for me, I've also seen that my number of answers questions has decreased and that one or more previous answers have been deleted along with the question. The total amount of reputation of those answers has matched the reputation drop.  This is most likely what happened to you.  If you go to your answers tab and click on "deleted recent answers" at the bottom, you'll probably see some questions of yours deleted that you didn't do yourself.

Comment: Note there is some sort of $60$ day cutoff where if a question or answer is deleted after that period, your reputation gained will not be lost. Also, there are other causes for your reputation to go down without it showing on your reputation tab, e.g., reversal of some irregular voting, a user being deleted, etc., but I believe they generally occur less often.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, thanks for the information. However, that does not seem to be my case. I have only one deleted recent answer listed in my "deleted recent answers" tab, and it had score of -1.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, also, if I am not mistaken, the reputation decrease due to user deletion is still shown in the reputation tab (it is marked with "user was removed")

Comment: @YaniorWeg I don't believe I've ever had a reputation decrease due to a user deletion, so I don't know how that would appear. There are other users here with a lot more experience & knowledge about how this site works than I have, so perhaps one of them will respond and shed some light on what likely happened to your reputation.

Comment: Yanior Weg, go to rep and select the `show removed posts`. My rep was lost because some users deleted the question. Probably because some might see them as PSQs.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, thank you! That happens to be exactly my case. That also means that the answers to the deleted questions do not count as "deleted recent answers" and thus are not shown in "deleted recent answers" tab, despite they were recently deleted with the question... Now I understand what has happened...

Comment: Some related older posts: [Where reputation disappears](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18884), [Number of awarded points is not being displayed correctly.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20060), [I miss 10 rep points](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15028), etc.